# Running unionByName on Spark 2.2.0

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, union

I am trying to run a unionByName command to combine two dataframes, but when I run my script, the log shows me that "DataFrame object has no attribute 'unionByName'".

`df_new = old.unionByName(old2, allowMissingColumns=True)`

I sense that it has to do with my Spark or Python version as union is working perfectly fine. The version is 2.2.0.cloudera1. How can I use a newer version of Spark or even use the unionByName command with my existing version?

I also see this in my log

`File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-4.0.0/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module`

So I sense that I am using Python 2.7?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`unionByName`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName)

> New in version 2.3.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but does that refer to python or spark? If Python, then why does it not recognize the command?

Comment: @Niels your spark version is 2.2 ... Nothing related to python

Comment: So unionByName is not available for my Spark version right?

Comment: @Niels yes exactly

Comment: Okay thank you. Then I need to somehow update.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between this function and union() is that this function resolves columns by name (not by position). So if you can do it without change version create a dataframe by reordering your `old2` DataFrame.
for example if your DataFrames is as below:

> old ("col1","col2","col3")

> old2("col3","col1","col2")

use something like below:

```
old3 = old2.select(col("col1"),col("col2"),col("col3"));

new_old = old.union(old3);
```

Comment: And can I allow missing columns? Or does the count of columns has to be the exact same?

Comment: In union the number of columns must be equal. So create a null column after select by `.withColumn("col3",lit(null))`.